# Delete a subscription

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I have connected stripe accounts to a stripe account. Various subscriptions are created in a connected account , Now i have to detele a subscription using the subscription ID provided with Stripe API. How to delete a subscription created in connected accounts?

Comment: Check this link, this may help. https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/canceling-pausing

Comment: I want to delete subscription from a connected account using the platform secret key.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make an API request with Stripe, you use your Secret API key `sk_test_1234`. If you act as a platform, you also need to tell Stripe which account you are creating the request on behalf of. This is done using the `Stripe-Account` header as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header).

This applies to any request made server-side from creating a charge to retrieving a customer or canceling a subscription.